# Using bold cells to pull data in the same row onto another page

Tags: vba, excel

I have a big workbook that has new pages being added to it. These pages are all names Week(x). I have macros to cycle through and collect data to display it on a summary page.

However, I would like to have a page where I can show certain data. This macro will be going through all the "Week()" Pages and looking for bold in column C. Once it sees that I want it to copy cells C:E and past it in cells D:F on the new page.

I have a decent amount of experience but I would love a little help on this one. I can also include the code, this is my first time posting so I will post it below.

```
Sub Front_Page() 
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long 

For Each ws In Worksheets 
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Calenders" And ws.Name <> "Front Page" Then
         For i = 1 To 100 
             If Cells(i, 3).FONT.Bold Then 
                ws.Rang("C:E").Select              
                Selection.Copy 
                ActiveSheet.Range("D5:F5").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
    End If 
Next i 
End If 
Next ws 
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Front_Page()
 
 Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
 
 
 For Each ws In Worksheets
     If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Calenders" And ws.Name <> "Front Page" Then
            
            
 
      
        For i = 1 To 100
        
            If Cells(i, 3).FONT.Bold Then
        
                ws.Range("C:E").Select
                
                Selection.Copy
                ActiveSheet.Range("D5:F5").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
            End If
 
         Next i
 
     End If
   
 
 Next ws
 
 End Sub

Comment: tell us where is your problem as your code seems to be 'ok' at glimpse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Front_Page()
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("D1000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Calenders" _
                                And ws.Name <> "Front Page" Then
            For i = 1 To 100
                If ws.Cells(i, 3).Font.Bold Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 4).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                                      ws.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 3).Value
                    lastrow = lastrow + 1
                End If
            Next i

        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, this worked wonderfully. Thank you so much. What did you see that was so transparent in my error? If you can't answer no worries.

Comment: `Cells()` should always have a qualifying worksheet reference, or it will refer to the ActiveSheet. you can't use End(xlUp) on a multiple-column range (it will just default to the first cell in the range and go up from that).  Missing "e" here `ws.Rang("C:E")`